# How to do math in batch-file

Tags: batch-file

I have been having troubles with batch-codes that I would expect to work, but don't...

Below is what I have written...

```dos
@echo off
cls

:loop
set /p "input=Input a number: "
set /a "number=%input%" 2>nul
REM check if input valid
if "%input%" NEQ "%number%" (
cls
Echo Please Enter a valid number! &Echo.&Echo.
goto :loop
)
Set /a Even=number%%2
if %Even% EQU 0 (
Echo Substituting Even Number in: x / 2
Echo set /p"=(%number%) / 2 = "
set /a answer=number/2
) Else (
Echo Substituting Odd Number in: 3x - 1
<nul set /p"=3(%number%)-1 = "
set /a answer=number*3
set /a answer=answer-1
)
Echo %answer%
Echo.
Echo.

goto :loop
Echo Unexpected Error . . .
pause
Exit
```

Whenever I input a number into the console, it does the math, like I want it to, but prints the number -1, and every time i input another number, the number goes to -2, -3, -4, so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arithmetic inside a for loop batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118810/arithmetic-inside-a-for-loop-batch-file)

Comment: what I am confused about is that, the person that originally sent me the code, this whole thing works fine for them...

Comment: No, it doesn't, and the accepted answer to the question I linked explains exactly why it doesn't quite clearly in the first two paragraphs.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19966972/62576, which was placed on hold. The information at the bottom of that question (that explains why it was put on hold) also explains what you should do to get it reopened. None of that information includes "post a duplicate of this question as a new one with the missing information". Proper conduct here would be to edit that question with the missing information to allow it to be reopened, just like it instructs you to do in the help center link provided. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `setlocal enableextensions` at the beginning after the `@echo off`, e.g.

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
cls
```

Also, I think you would also need to use delayed variable expansion (usually denoted by `!var!`), which would change your script above to something like this:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
cls

:loop
set /p "input=Input a number: "
set /a number=!input! 2>nul
REM check if input valid
if "!input!" NEQ "!number!" (
cls
Echo Please Enter a valid number!
Echo.
Echo.
goto :loop
)
REM Make sure that it is an integer put in (just in case)
set /a int=!number! %% 1
if "!input!" NEQ "!int!" (
cls
Echo Please Enter a valid number!
Echo.
Echo.
goto :loop
)
Set /a Even=!number! %% 2
if !Even! EQU 0 (
Echo Substituting Even Number in: x / 2
set /a answer=!number! / 2
) Else (
Echo Substituting Odd Number in: 3x - 1
set /a answer=!number! * 3 - 1
)
Echo !answer!
Echo.
Echo.

goto :loop
```

I also would like to point out that I also fixed a few other bugs (`set /p` isn't of any use in this script at all, especially in where it is used, and also you need the modulus to find even/odd).

Answer (score 0):

The given answer didn't seem to work correctly.  The second check for a valid integer doesn't do what it's supposed to do.  The first input check handles all non-integer cases.  Delayed expansion isn't necessary and make sure to use == for strings and EQU for numerics.  Put in an exit condition too, since Ctrl-C is messy.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
cls

echo Just hit Enter/Return to exit

:loop
set input=
set /p "input=Input a number: "
if "%input%" == "" (
    echo exiting...
    exit/b 0
)

REM check if input valid
set /a "number=%input%"
if not "%input%" == "%number%" (
    cls
    echo Please enter an integer number
    echo.
    echo.
    goto :loop
)

Set /a Even=%number% %% 2
if %Even% EQU 0 (
    echo Substituting Even Number in: x / 2
    set /a answer=%number% / 2
) else (
    echo Substituting Odd Number in: 3x - 1
    set /a answer=%number% * 3 - 1
)
echo %answer%
echo.
echo.

goto :loop
```